# Terraform reporting error in locals and variables in an attribute

Tags: terraform

I am having **lookups.tf** file with the below content

```
locals {
  roles_mapping = {
    web    = "we"
    app    = "as"
    db     = "db"
    queue  = "qu"
    stream = "st"
  }

  environment_lookup = {
    dev  = "d"
    test = "t"
    int  = "i"
    prod = "p"
    prd  = "p"
    uat  = "a"
    poc  = "d"
    dr   = "r"
    lab  = "l"
  }

  region_lookup = {
    "Australia East"      = "aae"
    "Australia Southeast" = "aas"
  }

  region_pairs = {
    "Australia East"      = "Australia Southeast"
    "Australia Southeast" = "Australia East"
  }

  lookup_result = lookup(var.environment_lookup, var.environment)

  tags = merge(
    data.azurerm_resource_group.tf-azrg.tags, {
      Directory      = "bento.com",
      PrivateDNSZone = var.private_dns_zone,
      Immutable      = "False",
      ManagedOS      = "True",
    }
  )
}

data "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "log_analytics" {
  name                = "abc-az-lad1"
  resource_group_name = "abc-dev-aae"
}
```

Now, I have a file called **variables.tf**

```
variable "environment" {
  description = "The name of environment for the AKS Cluster"
  type        = string
  default     = "dev"
}

variable "identifier" {
  description = "The identifier for the AKS Cluster"
  type        = number
  default     = 001
}
```

Now, I want to refer **lookups.tf** and **variable.tf** in name in **main.tf** as below

```
resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "tf-alaw" {
  name                = var.tla-la-local.lookup_result-var.identifier
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.tf-azrg.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.tf-azrg.name
  sku                 = var.la_sku
  retention_in_days   = 30
}
```

However, I get an error like the below:

```
Error: Reference to the undeclared input variable

  on ..\..\..\terraform-azurerm-aks\lookups.tf line 32, in locals:
  32:   lookup_result = lookup(var.environment_lookup, var.environment)

An input variable with the name "environment_lookup" has not been declared.
This variable can be declared with a variable "environment_lookup" {} block.

Error: Reference to the undeclared input variable

  on ..\..\..\terraform-azurerm-aks\main.tf line 2, in resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "tf-alaw":
   2:   name                = var.tla-la-local.lookup_result-var.identifier

An input variable with the name "tla-la-local" has not been declared. This
variable can be declared with a variable "tla-la-local" {} block.
```

Do note that the name below, what I expect is **var.tla** refers to a variable  then string/text **-la-** now **local.lookup_result** is a value from locals and then again a text **-** finally referring another variable **var.identifier**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a different syntax when `locals` block is defined. This should be added instead of what you currently have:

```
lookup_result = lookup(local.environment_lookup, var.environment)
```

More information and examples here: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/locals.html#using-local-values.

EDIT1: I just saw your note under the error output. So, when you are concatenating multiple variables you still have to use the "old" syntax, i.e., similar to what was used in Terraform 0.11.x. Here's how that value needs to look like:

```
"${var.tla}-la-${local.lookup_result}-${var.identifier}"
```

Comment: I realized my mistake. What I learnt is using old syntax for concatenation and the second thing is locals to be referenced with local. and variables to be referenced with var.